# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm passing a value to codeigniter function for getting a result.
But the ajax value does not pass to the php function.

My script function follows :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<Script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#up").on('click',function(){
      if ($("#incdec").val() < $(this).data("max")) {
        $("#incdec").val(parseInt($("#incdec").val())+1);
        }
});

$("#down").on('click',function(){
      if ($("#incdec").val() > $(this).data("min")) {
        $("#incdec").val(parseInt($("#incdec").val())-1);
      }
 });
 });
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".butt").on('click',function(){
    var e=$(".aa").val();
    alert(e);

    $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         data:"id="+e,
         url:"<?php echo site_url('pages/getit');?>",
         success: function(html){
              $('#'+dataprocess).html(html);
         }
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

My HTML code :

```
<input type="text" name="incdec" id="incdec" value="0" class="aa"/>
<input type="button" class="butt"  id="up" value="Up" data-max="5" />
<input type="button" id="down" value="Down" data-min="0" class="butt"/>

<div id="dataprocess"></div>
```

But I'm getting an error as follows:

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLDivElement]`

Please help me find my mistake.

Comment: `$('#dataprocess').html(html);` instead of `$('#'+dataprocess).html(html);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this bit of code:

```
success: function(html){
    $('#'+dataprocess).html(html);
}
```

you are appending a string, namely **'#'**, to an object, **dataprocess**.

The object is converted to a string, **'[object HTMLDivElement]'**, which tells its type.

Try this instead:

```
success: function(html){
    $('#dataprocess').html(html);
}
```

**EDIT:**

The way jquery selectors work, in this case the 'by-id' selector, you have the 'id' marker, **'#'**, **immediately** followed by the id of the control you are trying to select, in this case **'dataprocess'**.

Here is a useful resource about jquery selectors:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: ya i got it but that value cant pass to php function

Comment: @Me Uraj: I don't understand. Could you rephrase a bit? What value can you not pass?

Comment: `data:"id="+e,
url:"<?php echo site_url('pages/getit');?>",` here above `id` value pass to that controller function

Comment: Well, your question was about the error you were getting. This is a different question, I am not sure I understand what it is though.

Comment: As far as I understand, you are wondering why your data, from the ajax call, is not coming back to your div. That is because you get this error, in the success function. Try first correcting as I, and the other commenters, recommended, then try again. If it is still not working, then you should investigate what other problems you get. For now just see if that specific Uncaught Error is gone.

Comment: i cleared my error. with your comment very thanks but i want to pass that value to the controller function

Comment: I am happy to hear this solved the original issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this ajax as blw:**

```
$('#dataprocess').html(html);
```